# Выравнивание текста и иконки

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Верстаю кнопку с иконкой. Как обычно иконка находится слева, следом идёт текст. Текст с иконкой выровнены по центру кнопки(по горизонтали и вертикали.). При этом ширина кнопки зависит он ширины родительского элемента, и текст кнопки может переноситься на две строки, но текст и иконка при этом должны продолжать быть выровнены по центру кнопки.

Comment: Код приложите .

Answer (score 4):

Вариант 1:

```css
/* Врап для иконки и текста */
.item  {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
}

/* Иконка */
i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5rem;
}


/* Доп. стилизация для наглядности примера */

/* Врап для иконки и текста */
.item {
  max-width: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
/* Иконка */
i {
  display: block;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background: #ccc;
}
/* Текст */
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
  <div class="item">
    <i></i>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <i></i>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
  </div>
```

Вариант 2 flex:

```css
.item  {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
}


/* Доп. стилизация для наглядности примера */
.item {
  max-width: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

i {
  display: block;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-right: .5rem;
}

span {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <i></i>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <i></i>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
  </div>
```

Вариант 3 table:

```css
.item  {
    display: table;
}

.icon {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Доп. стилизация для наглядности примера */
.item {
  max-width: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.icon {
  width: 1rem;
  
  padding-right: .5rem;
}

.icon i {
  display: block;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <span class="icon"><i></i></span>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <span class="icon"><i></i></span>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: плюсик от меня Леночка

Answer (score 2):

Надеюсь это то, что вы искали. Вот рабочий пример:

```css
.parent {
  width: 130px;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button>
    <span class="icon">&#x2709;</span>
    Send e-mail to Mr.Smith
  </button>
</div>
```